# Resharper naming convention rule for void methods

Tags: naming-conventions, resharper

Does anyone know how (or if it's possible) to create a Resharper naming convention rule that doesn't allow void methods to start with "Get"?

So this would be fine:

```
public string GetFoo();
```

But the rule would complain about this:

```
public void GetFoo();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really add this as a naming convention, but you could create a [search pattern](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/) that will look for void methods starting with Get, and flag them with a Warning or Error.

For this, go to ReSharper's Options, then `Code Inspection → Custom Patterns`:

- Click `Add Pattern`
- In the new dialog, select `Find`
  [image]
- Type in the following pattern: `void $method$($args$){ $stmt$ }`, and press `Add Placeholder → Extract from pattern`. This should create 3 placeholders in the list.
- Double click the `method` placehoder, and add the following RegEx: `^Get.*`
  [image]
- In the `Pattern Severity` combobox select `Show as Warning` or `Show as Error`, depending on your preference.
- In the description, write something like `Void methods should not begin with Get`.
- Click `Add`, then Save (or Save To → Team Shared, to have this pattern stored in the team-shared settings, available to all your teammates).

ReSharper will now flag all void methods that start with Get:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: great answer - do you have an idea how we could exclude methods that have a particular attribute?  [TestMethod] or [Test]  we would want to exclude from this rule.

Comment: another question... is there a way to exclude methods that have 'out' parameters?